# Check if site is playing audio in iframe element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I would like to know how can I check if iframe element on my site is currently playing audio or if it is paused. I have this embedded soundclound link and button to control it:

```
<iframe width="50%" height="100" id="audio" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/339767079&amp;color=%23ff5500&amp;auto_play=false"></iframe>
<button id="play-bt">CLick</button>
```

And this script:

```
var audioplayer = document.getElementById("audio");
$("#play-bt").click(function(){
  if (audioplayer.paused) {
    audioplayer.play();
    alert("playing");
  }
  else {
    audioplayer.pause();
    alert("not playing");
  }
  $(this).toggleClass('pause');
})
```

But this jquery doesnt seem to work for me. How can I check if the site is playing audio and then alert it?
Thank you for any advice.

Comment: The iframe `src` is cross-domain, so you will not be able to access it. What you're attempting to achieve is not possible, unless SoundCloud has an SDK/API you can use to know if the current user is listening to a file.

Comment: violate the same-origin policy?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I thought that. Well unfortunately, Soundcloud API is currently unavailable. So I cant do anything about it?